# IIS7 error when calling non-activeX dll from COM+ activeX dll called by classic asp

Tags: delphi, iis-7, asp-classic, activex

I have a classic ASP application that works fine on older versions of IIS but not on IIS7.

The ASP code calls COM+ ActiveX DLLs (written in VB6) and I have managed to get everything running fine except for one program where the ActiveX DLL calls another 3rd party non-ActiveX DLL.

At that point, I get **"error 800706be"**.

I'm not sure what to do here. Here's what I have tried:

- I thought it may have something to do with permissions so, just to test, I have granted "Full Control" to IIS_IUSRs for the non-ActiveX DLL - That hasn't solved the problem
- I know that the COM+ component that calls the non-ActiveX DLL is not the problem because I am able to call other methods in that component without any problems. Then I see the component running in Component Services.

Can anyone help me out?

**Edit**: 8000706BE translates to "The remote procedure call failed". Not very helpful, is it?

**Edit**
Hi - thanks for the comments. I got the providers of the 3rd party DLL to recompile it as an ActiveX DLL and now it works fine on IIS7.

The 3rd party DLL was written in Delphi - at first they tried recompiling it with the latest Delphi version but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

looks odd try this tool to help.

> ADPlus is a tool from Microsoft Product Support Services (PSS) that can troubleshoot any process or application that stops responding (hangs) or fails (crashes). Frequently, you can use ADPlus (ADPlus.vbs) as a replacement tool for the Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS) Exception Monitor (6.1/7.1) and User Mode Process Dump. These are two separate tools that PSS frequently uses to isolate what causes a process to stop responding (hang) or quit unexpectedly (crash) in a Microsoft Windows DNA environment.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350/